# how to change URLs in cakephp through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am using cakephp 1.3 and I want the user not to see the traditional cake php urls like:

sitename.com/users/contact, instead I want to use .htaccess to mod_rewrite and generate nice URLs like: sitename.com/contact.

How can I do this using cake phps .htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using .htaccess rewrite rules would be quite pointless, since Cake would still generate all links "the Cake way", being completely oblivious to any rewritten URLs.

Instead, use [Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration) to configure special URLs for certain actions. These will be reverse-routable, meaning anywhere you tell Cake to make a link for `array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar')`, it will use the configured short route. Example:

```
Router::connect('/foo', array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));

echo $html->link('FooBar', array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'));
// <a href="/foo">FooBar</a>
```